# HTML img src format?

Tags: html

I have an API that I can get a "snapshot" from my IP camera. If I use this line my browser returns and image.

```
http://my_NAS_IP:PORT/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version="8"&cameraId=1&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera"&preview=true&method="GetSnapshot"&_sid=SESSION_ID
```

but when I try to put this into an html it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img src="my_NAS_IP:PORT/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version="8"&cameraId=1&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera"&preview=true&method="GetSnapshot"&_sid=SESSION_ID" 
/>

</body>
</html>
```

To many `"` in the line? How can I format this to give me an image on the page?

Comment: Use single quotes to replace one of the sets of double quotes.

Comment: Please research HTML encoding.

Comment: Do you include `http://` in location bar but expect auto-detection in HTML source or it's just a typo? Does the camera return a picture or a full web site?

Comment: Just a typo on the `http://`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot use `"` character inside a quote that is surrounded by `"`. Use single quotes `'` for the outer string.

Answer (score 1):

Just enclose your `img` tag in single quotes

```
<img src='my_NAS_IP:PORT/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version="8"&cameraId=1&api="SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera"&preview=true&method="GetSnapshot"&_sid=SESSION_ID'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="my_NAS_IP:PORT/webapi/entry.cgi?camStm=1&version='8'&cameraId=1&api='SYNO.SurveillanceStation.Camera'&preview=true&method='GetSnapshot'&_sid=SESSION_ID" 
/>
```

Use single quotes within ...